# iOS: Intermittently slow network requests

Tags: ios, swift, networking

I have an iOS application that has two requests that have large response objects and typically take ~100-200ms to complete when connectivity is good. When connectivity is average these requests seem to get hung-up somewhere ~20% of the time and I've had them take anywhere from 30 to 60s. I'll then restart the app and try the request again seconds later and it will complete in the expected time (100-200 ms)

I've tested the api that the endpoints are querying with other clients (cURL, Postman) and haven't had any issue so I'm fairly certain this has to do with my front-end configuration. I'm using the Alamofire library to handle the requests.

Here's the code for one of the requests:

```
func login(_ params: [String: String], completion: @escaping (Response<UserResponseSuccess, UserResponseFail>) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request(self.url!, method: .post, parameters: params).responseJSON {
            response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                let respJSON: JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                    // do stuff with json
                    let resp = UserResponseSuccess()
                    completion(Response.success(resp))
                } else {
                    logRequestError()
                    let resp = UserResponseFail()
                    completion(Response.failure(resp))
                }
            } else {
                logServerError()
                let resp = UserResponseFail()
                completion(Response.failure(resp))
            }
        }
    }
```

And here's the request log:

```
2019-08-17 14:03:16.832462-0600 Debug - foo[17418:3273774] CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    ptcl = htps;
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sdmn = "foo.bar.com";
    srvr = "foo.bar.com";
    sync = syna;
}
$ curl -v \
    -X POST \
    -H "User-Agent: Debug - foo/1.3 (com.foo.bar.debug; build:4; iOS 12.4.0) Alamofire/4.7.3" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" \
    -H "Accept-Language: en-US;q=1.0" \
    -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip;q=1.0, compress;q=0.5" \
    -d "email=foo@foo.com&password=bar123" \
    "https://rtj.foo.com/users/login"
```

The requests either go through instantly or don't hit the server. I could probably have these timeout and then retry the request but I don't want to cover up a probable bug.

This also seems to happen more often on a cell network than wifi.

Update: I ran the same query with URLSession instead of Alamofire and received similar results. The error output from the query is:

```
error: 
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." 
UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x28228fe10 {Error 
Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo= . 
{_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=60, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, 
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://foo.bar.com/users/login, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://foo.bar.com/users/login, 
_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=60, 
NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
```

Versioning: Alamofire: 4.7.3, Xcode version: 10.3, Swift version: 5

Comment: Try using UrlSession directly in a test app and see if the behavior changes. You can get much more data viewing delegate based updates.

Comment: Another idea - use a Mac and curl, tether to your phone that’s on cellular only - see if anything changes. Use Bluetooth to tether.

Comment: Thanks David. Going to start with UrlSession but I like the phone curl idea as well.

Comment: I just updated my question with results from the URLSession output. I still haven't had this issue occur on wifi. Going to try a different client on my phone and maybe even hotspot my computer.

Comment: I was able to get the request to time out with `HTTBot` on my phone so the issue is independent of the application in question. That would probably make it a server issue.

Comment: Change the timeout to say 3 minutes instead of default 60 seconds.

Comment: From a debug standpoint, I've had them complete in 45 seconds so I know it's just a log request/response cycle. What I don't know is why. I could shorten the timeouts on the client and do retries when this happens as it usually doesn't happen twice in a row.

Comment: So run a parallel ping service and see if it’s network or server. Quinn of Apple highly discourages 60 second timeouts on cellular.

Comment: I take back my previous comment. It is almost certainly a network issue because I can rapid fire requests all day on wifi and they always work. Also, I just triggered a timeout with my computer connected to my wifi hotspot.

Comment: You have any suggestions on how to handle this (assuming I'm right) outside of creating some sort of timeout/retry policy?